# How to interpret the graph representing the fit provided by the ARIMA model?

Tags: r, time-series, forecast, graphical-model

I'm following this tutorial [here](https://www.datascience.com/blog/introduction-to-forecasting-with-arima-in-r-learn-data-science-tutorials) to build an ARIMA model in R.

I've done a Forecast using a fitted model in R. I specified the forecast horizon h periods ahead for predictions to be made and used the fitted model to generate those predictions. Then I plotted them to see the results and this is what I got:

[image]

The light blue line above is supposed to show the fit provided by the model.

In the Tutorial this is what they got (their Dataset is different from mine):

[image]

In their case it is clear in contrast with mine. Can somebody provide me with an explanation regarding the graph that I got. Does it make any sense? Does it tell something or is what I got completely wrong (knowing that I followed the tutorial as it is)?

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Here's my code :

```
  #Removing Outliers

  count_ts = ts(df[, c('qty')])

  df$clean_qty = tsclean(count_ts)


   df$cnt_ma = ma(df$clean_qty, order=7) # using the clean count with no outliers
   df$cnt_ma30 = ma(df$clean_qty, order=30)
   #Data Decomposition
   count_ma = ts(na.omit(df$cnt_ma), frequency=30)
   decomp = stl(count_ma, s.window="periodic")
   deseasonal_cnt <- seasadj(decomp)

   fit2 = arima(deseasonal_cnt, order=c(1,1,7))
   fcast <- forecast(fit2, h=30)
   plot(fcast)
```

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: @Leevo , just added it , thank you.